# Tablets are not splitting

Tags: accumulo

I am ingesting large amount of data into my Accumulo database.

My tablet split threshold is 4G.

During the work of my program I see the tablets filling up and when any of them gets larger than 4G a new tablet is created but **always stays empty**.

Eventually I see than there are >200 tablets created (initial number was 30) but all of them are empty - verified with the following command:

```
hadoop fs -du -h /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/
```

the results:

`16.9 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/default_tablet
16.4 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000cr6
16.6 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000cr7
16.3 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000cr8
17.3 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000cr9
17.2 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000cra
18.4 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crb
16.9 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crc
16.5 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crd
17.4 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000cre
16.4 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crf
16.5 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crg
16.3 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crh
17.6 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000cri
16.9 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crj
16.8 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crk
17.1 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crl
17.4 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crm
17.2 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crn
17.1 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000cro
17.4 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crp
19.8 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crq
17.0 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crr
16.6 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crs
16.7 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crt
16.7 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000cru
17.7 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crv
16.7 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crw
16.7 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000crx
16.2 G  /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0000cry
0       /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-000109c
0       /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-000118l
0       /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-00011bv
0       /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-00011cs
0       /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-00011nx
0       /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0001212
0       /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-0001238
0       /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-00012a3
0       /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-00012gn
0       /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-00012ku
0       /apps/accumulo/data/tables/3/t-00012nf`

all the rest of the tablets are empty too.

This doesn't make sense to me and I am afraid it slows down the ingestion rate. Is it a known issue? What aren't the tablet servers split as expected?

Comment: Are you getting any warnings or log messages?

Comment: @BinaryNerd No, I am using Ambari to manage the clusters and I don't see anything

Comment: One reason a tablet won't split is when you have massive keys. Accumulo wont split a key across tablets. What does your data look like? Even though you're using Ambari you should still be able to get to the Accumulo web front end. Also, have you tried forcing a major compaction on the table from the CLI?

Comment: @BinaryNerd thanks for the comment, I checked the logs and there are no errors, I saw a lot of major compactions in the Accumulo management page. What do you mean by massive keys?

Comment: If you go into a tablet, how many rf files are in there? Well if your row key has low cardinality, ie the rowKey is `A` and you have 10B values they will have to go in a single tablet, you cannot split on the rowKey. Ideally the higher the cardinality the better.

Comment: Out of interest, if you get the CLI to print the split points in your table, what do they look like?

Comment: @BinaryNerd the rowKey is different over the entire database. I see 36 rfiles in one of the tablets. the split points look like this: `\x01, \x01\x00\xF7P, \x01\x00\xF7l, .......` with different lengths

Comment: I would take a look at the tablet logs on one of the nodes next.

Comment: You wouldn't see errors if you have large rows that can't split. You should see warnings, though (depends on your log configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Accumulo Tablets can refer to files that are outside of their directory in HDFS (as opposed to HBase in this regard). You can verify this looking at the contents of the accumulo.metadata table if you are brave :)

Compact the table and then re-run your check over the contents of HDFS. After the compactions finish, each tablet would uniquely refer to a file in its own directory.

The other explanation (albeit unlikely) would be that your data was so skewed such that data only resided in the upper or lower half of the Tablet's "key space" (and thus only one daughter of the split contained data).